# Users file to map users between SVN and Git

Tags: git, svn

When migrating from SVN to Git, [this site](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) recommends using a file named users.txt. Suppose I used the name John Smith when I installed git on my system, and email is john@smith.com. I created a Github account with the ID John2. My ID on svn is smith1.

what should users.txt look like? Version A?

```
               smith1 = John Smith <john@smith.com>
```

or version B?

```
              smith1 = John2 <john@smith.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whichever you prefer to show.

Email is the important part for [github binding](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address?platform=mac#setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).